# Securing data in untrusted environments

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine

I have been looking but cannot find a good answer that can help me in my case. To explain the situation, I am creating a Unity3D game which will have a multiplayer system. 
  In order to keep the player data as secure as possible (so people doesn't cheat easily), I decided to implement a Web API 2 service that connects to a SQL Server database. 
I designed the Web service in such a way that only if the request contains specific data the request is processed.
 What I am now having problem is to design a solution that will let me send/retrieve data from the web service. 
I implemented SHA-512 to send the password so packet sniffers wouldn't get it in plain text, and I am planning to implement HTTPS but Unity classes makes it very hard. I thought of implementing RijdnaelManaged as a more secure algorithm for the accounts but in Unity the code is easily reverse-engineered.

Would this model be secure enough to stop script kiddies from hacking player accounts?

Comment: unless you implement a login mechanism for user, encryption/https etc will not solve your problem. You should store the critical data on the server (per user) and not trust the data(rep points, levels etc) sent from your client.

Comment: @EZI A login system is already implemented. Upon starting the game, the user will have to either login or create an account

Comment: Then you can only send the user's *action* to the server, not the *state* of the client.

Comment: @EZI, and how would I get the user's progress which is continuous if I do not trust what the user sends me?

Comment: Suppose your game make moves with arrow keys, You can post that moves(not necessarily every move) to the server, to calculate its position on the map. (When I say *"don't trust the client"* I mean don't try its `state` like *"I am at level 10"* or *"I have that much money"* )

Comment: @EZI I am not sure if I am entirely following you. For example, the user finishes a missison and a certain reward is given, are you saying the reward should be given by the server and not the client?

Comment: Yes, following the user's *actions* (client sends *I moved there*, *I picked up this thing*, *I turned to left* etc) server should determine that client has won the award, not because it says *I got it*.

Comment: Wouldn't that add a significant overhead to the game? I mean, if there are 500 users playing at the same time all connecting to the Web API service, would that still be transparent to the user? I am afraid of making it slow because of network issues.

Comment: This is the trade-off of security. (`would that still be transparent to the user?` depends on network speed, how much data you send to server etc.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the information. I would accept you as solution if you had posted an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTTPS**

> I implemented SHA-512 to send the password so packet sniffers wouldn't get it in plain text,

That's not helping for as far as your webservice goes, it now uses the hash as its password, so anybody sniffing it will still capture it.

Use https, not http to get it right.

If you really cannot: build a system where the service first issues a challenge, and where the client then "signs" that challenge and sends the signature back. That's still by far not as good as https, but it'll prevent a few things (but not e.g. a man-in-the-middle attack).

**Security**

If you look at analyzing the risks, you need to take care to address users of your game as well as 3rd parties.

The 3rd parties, with good passwords (good luck with that) or proper 2 factor authentication, https etc. you can cover the bases rather well. Add in some security in the webservices and you should be a good way along the path.

But you also have to deal with users of the game. And that's harder than it might seem as they could run your game in a debugger and figure out how the game communicates with the server and what it sends when, what the effects are of that etc. Nw if you have a multi-player game typically that involves virtual goods and/or currency that can be obtained and/or traded. Devious players will try to get it the easy way, so you need to protect somehow against that as well.
The easiest to do that is to move the game logic into the server and use the client only for visualizing things - but that obviously means you make much more use of server resources ... 
Trusting your client is running, unmodified, and you're talking to it: you can't ...

Comment: Okay, so I totally have to implement HTTPS... The "base" of the game is a single object that contains everything, that object is sent serialized in protobuf-net so any change at all that was not made by the game will completely destroy the object. Not in-game-obtained objects/currency will be completely managed by the server and the Google Play store, still unsure of how.

Comment: Remember SSL (https uses SSL) protects the data only while it is in transit between two endpoints, not on either endpoint. Essentially your server cannot be 100% sure it's talking to your client. You can put up hurdles and obfuscate things, but they can be passed by a willing attacker relatively easy.